# back button handling wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

My problem is that I have a list. When I long press a particular item in the list then it opens a context menu and when I click on a menu item inside context menu then it opens a  popup,so on pressing the hardware back button i want that i again go back to the list.
so for doing this my code is:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(object sender,System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (calendarDescripton.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            calendarDescripton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

    }
```

After using this code when I click the button that opens the list,the application exits,it does not open list also.

Answer (score 0):

I think first the Navigation should be canceled, before making any other changes. Try this

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(object sender,System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (calendarDescripton.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        calendarDescripton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

If this doesn't help, place a break piont at the if condition and check if it is entering inside the if or not

If the break point doesn't hit, means there is something wrong with your Navigation approach.

If you are using NavigationService.Navigate() method for page navigation, it should work.
Otherwise, if you are using, 
`App.Current.RootVisual = new MyPage();`, then BackKey cannot be overridden.

Comment: no its not working n by debug point is also nt wrking at onbackkeyopress method